# How do I update the parent dependency of a dependency not included in pom?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, java-ee-6

A library (guava 11.0.2) is found to be vulnerable in my security scan and needs to be updated. However, it is not included in pom.xml file. I believe it's because that library was included as a dependency to some other library included in my project. I want to know which parent library actually included it.

Is there a way that I can know what all dependencies use that library so that I can update those dependencies in pom?

Comment: use `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Actually "parent dependency" is a confusing term because it is reminiscent of parent POMs.